# Javascript variable change with onclick

Tags: javascript, variables, checkbox, onclick

I want to have a variable changed within a checkbox that causes an if statement to compute without reloading the page, but I'm struggling... still learning, sorry!

Here's the relevant code:

```
 <!--Variable declaration-->
 <script type="text/javascript"> var lettuce = false; </script>

 <!--The following line is within a form-->
 <input type="checkbox" onclick="lettuce=true" name="food" value="lettuce" /> Lettuce<br />

 <--the if statement-->
 <script type="text/javascript">    
      if (lettuce == true) {
    document.write("45");   
  }
 </script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Also the comments were added above -- the problem with the comment above the if statement is not the issue.

Answer (score 5):

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="lettuce=this.checked; recompute();" name="food" value="lettuce" /> Lettuce<br />

<script type="text/javascript">
function recompute()    
      if (lettuce == true) {
    document.write("45");   
  }
}
 </script>
```

First, you want the `onchange` event, which is called when the state of the checkbox changes. The `this.checked` returns the boolean value (true or false) depending on that state. Second, the `if` statement is only processed once, when the page loads that script. Place it in a function to call it again.

Comment: -1 lettuce will always be true, as onchange will fire both when it's checked and when it's unchecked

Comment: @AlienWebguy: I caught that right after re-reading my post. It has been changed.

Answer (score 3):

First, your logic will never set lettuce to false. I understand that we should eat more lettuce, but we should still give the user a choice ;)

Secondly, try to keep your Javascript out of the html:

```
 <!--Variable declaration-->
 <script type="text/javascript"> var lettuce = false; </script>

 <!--The following line is within a form-->
 <input type="checkbox" id="lettuce" name="food" value="lettuce" /> Lettuce<br />

 <script type="text/javascript">  
      document.getElementById('lettuce').addEventListener('click',checkLettuce,false);
      function checkLettuce(){ 

          if (document.getElementById('lettuce').checked === true) {
             lettuce = true;
             document.write("45");  
          } 
          else
          {
             lettuce = false;
          }
      }
 </script>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/renut/

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the if statement into a function and then call the function in the onclick event.

```
 <!--Variable declaration-->
 <script type="text/javascript"> var lettuce = false; </script>

 <!--The following line is within a form-->
 <input type="checkbox" onclick="my_function();" name="food" value="lettuce" /> Lettuce<br />

 <!--the if statement-->
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function my_function() {
          if (lettuce == true) {
              lettuce = false;
          } else {
              lettuce = true;
              document.write("45");
          }
      }
 </script>
```

Comment: -1 That will set lettuce to true, but it will never set it back.

Comment: And where was that part of the requirements?

Comment: Well the OP could have had other parts of the code setting it to be false. But whatever, I edited it anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call a function in your onclick, because the script you have now:

```
if(lettuce == true){
    document.write("45");   
}
```

Executes before your onclick ever occurs.

Try this:

```
 <!--The following line is within a form-->
 <input type="checkbox" onclick="clicked(true);" name="food" value="Lettuce" /> Lettuce<br />
 <input type="checkbox" onclick="clicked(false);" name="food" value="Carrot" /> Carrot<br />
 <input type="checkbox" onclick="clicked(false);" name="food" value="Cool Beans" /> Cool Beans<br />
 <input type="checkbox" onclick="clicked(false);" name="food" value="Pepper" /> Pepper<br />
 <--the if statement-->
 <script type="text/javascript">    
    function clicked(lettuce){
         if(lettuce)
             alert('You toggled Lettuce!');
         else
             alert('You toggled some other vegetable!');
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: -1 Your code forces lettuce to always be true: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/QaYJ4/

Comment: @AlienWebGuy, it sets it true in the onclick, just like he wanted. No reason for a minus 1 when it has the same functionality as what the OP intended.

Comment: @AlienWebGuy, it's not forced to be true, because he could easily call the function with false as a parameter instead, but in his example code he set it to true in the onclick, which is essentially exactly what this does.

Comment: A checkbox is a toggler. Let me ask you this - would you use the code you provided, how it is, on your own website? Assuming of course JQuery was prohibited.

Comment: @AlienWebGuy no haha, I'd remove the event handler from the html and bind it separately, but that's confusing for beginners, so I left it in for him, and I wouldn't name my variable lettuce haha, but other that that sure! And regardless of whether or not I'd use it, it is a correct answer to the OP's problem and therefore doesn't warrant a downvote. He might have another element he wants to add a call to that sets lettuce false. You don't know what the OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: var lettuce > var carrot! haha ok edit your post and i'll remove the downvote

Comment: @AlienWebGuy, can I edit it to use carrot instead? :P No, but really I figure the votes locked in by now anyways isn't it?

Comment: Haha yes carrot! If you edit your answer, it unlocks it for 7 minutes :)

Comment: @AlienWebGuy Does that look better?

Comment: @Thanks :) I just had to add `Cool beans` into the garden too after you said that :P

Answer (score 0):

Setting `lettuce=true` wont cause your if statement to run.  You just need to write a function that will run when your checkbox is clicked.

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="functionName()".../>Lettuce</br/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function functionName(){
    document.write("45");
}
</script>
```

functionName() is called when the check box is clicked.

Comment: I got whipped by about 4 people to that answer haha

Answer (score 0):

Seeing javascript functions being invoked inline from an html element makes me cringe a little.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkLettuce" name="food" value="lettuce" /> Lettuce<br />

 <--the if statement-->

 <script type="text/javascript"> 
   var chkLettuce = document.getElementById("chkLettuce");
   chkLettuce.onclick = chkLettuce.click = function() {
      lettuce = !!chkLettuce.checked;
      if(lettuce){
         alert('45 or whatever');
      }
   }
 </script>
```